"FILLMODE= Solid" from CrossSectionMeshGeometryModel3D Is Not working really, it went into hollow mesh
3D hollowBox into SolidBox
The project What Im tring now include to see a crosssectinoal surface (like a scratched face).
That is I would like to see the crosssectional cut surface as a solid material or fullfilled with solid type, but after using this custom class provided by helixtoolkitsharpDX, it was filled as a real solid filling on cutting surface.
It was rendered by htkSharpDX as a 3D hollow mesh box, not a real solid mesh box.
The build-in attribue "FIllMODE = SOLID" can not also make a real solid.
3D Hollow Meshing into SolidMesh
Hello Freindsss,
Hope you are good,
I would like to discuss about my facing condition.
I'm using helixtoolkitSharpDX for making some visualizable 3D profile.
In my test project, I need to see a crosssectional view from a cutting plane.
So, I chose H.T.K.SharpDX and referenced "CrosssectionMeshGeometryModel3D" class that is a custom class.
The project What Im tring now include to see a crosssectinoal surface (like a scratched face).
That is I would like to see the crosssectional cut surface as a solid material or fullfilled with solid type, but after using this custom class provided by helixtoolkitsharpDX, it was filled as a real solid filling on cutting surface.
It was rendered by htkSharpDX as a 3D hollow mesh box, not a real solid mesh box.
The build-in attribue "FIllMODE = SOLID" can not also make a real solid.
I confirm it is the same in Car demo "CrossSectionDemo" provided by official resource (hollow although it seems to be solid)
So, I guess it is like a difference between Extrude function(Solid) and Surface Mesh(hollow) function in AutoCad.
I want a real solid meshing with htkSharpDX.
So, I would appreciate to your advices if you, guys have already experienced like me or similar kinds of event, and  if you share and discuss your thoughts.
Thank you,,,
Phyoe  . . .
